# How to implement "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Is it possible to implement "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header in asp.net

Answer (score 79, accepted):

From [enable-cors.org](http://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html):

> **CORS on ASP.NET**
>
> If you don't have access to configure IIS, you can still add the header through ASP.NET by adding the following line to your source pages:
>
> ```
> Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
> ```

*See also:* Configuring [IIS6](http://enable-cors.org/server_iis6.html) / [IIS7](http://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html)

Comment: +1 Thanks, But I need to add this header only for resource files e.g. css & js files

Comment: I have some js files which are frequently updated and i want to use them on other domain, but they wont work coz cross domain policy

Comment: Anyways I'll add this to whole site

Comment: How do you add it to the resource files?

Comment: At me, in the current version of c#, the accepted syntax was Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

Answer (score 33):

Another option is to add it on the web.config directly:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://www.yourSite.com" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

...
I found this in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31084417)

Comment: Is there a reason setting the value to a URL instead of a * doesn't work with json calls?

Answer (score 9):

1.Install-Package  **Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors**

2 . Add this code in **WebApiConfig.cs.**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services

    // Web API routes

    config.EnableCors();

    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

3. Add this

```
using System.Web.Http.Cors;
```

4. Add this code in Api Controller (**HomeController.cs**)

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Home/test")]
    public string test()
    {
       return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: this code allows CORS on specific action method and not a js file

Answer (score 1):

You would need an HTTP module that looked at the requested resource and if it was a css or js, it would tack on the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header with the requestors URL, unless you want it wide open with '*'.

Answer (score 1):

Configuring the CORS response headers on the server wasn't really an option. You should configure a proxy in client side.

Sample to Angular - So, I created a proxy.conf.json file to act as a proxy server. Below is my proxy.conf.json file:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:49389",
    "secure": true,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": "/api"
    },
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

Put the file in the same directory the package.json then I modified the start command in the package.json file like below

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"
```

now, the http call from the app component is as follows:

```
return this.http.get('/api/customers').map((res: Response) => res.json());
```

Lastly to run use **npm start** or **ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json**