# Get json data from another domain(cross domain)

Tags: asp.net, jquery, cross-domain

I am new to jquery and don't know to fetch json data from another domain(Cross domain).

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url){
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
if ("withCredentials" in xhr){
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
} else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined"){
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
} else {
    xhr = null;
}
return xhr;
}

var request = createCORSRequest("get", "http://www.stackoverflow.com/");
if (request){
request.onload = function() {
    // ...
};
request.onreadystatechange = handler;
request.send();
}
```

I found this program from here [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

This is saying by using above code we can access cross domain json data.

I copied the code. This is saying handler is undefined

I don't know how to define handler .

I also don't know what to write inside request.onload

where I will get the json result

Please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The handler is a function

it should be something like

```
function handler(){
   var response = xhr.responseText;
   // do more with your response.
}
```

Also you xhr should be defined outside of the function createCORSrequest.

See [docs on XDR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc288060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I know you said you are new to jquery but you should also look into  [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/). Its much easier.

Comment: Hi Praneeta
I am trying to access other domain data.
but it is showing error
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.10.13:8080. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

how to solve this problem.

Comment: You will have to add 'Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");' to your server side code.found it on this page [http://stackoverflow.com/q/6516591/1028488](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6516591/1028488) $.getJson can be used for accessing data from different domain(I use it all the time), but I am not sure how IE treats it.

Comment: Also once you are done testing on localhost & move it to a server, you can chnage th access control from * to you domain name (security)

Comment: Also I found jQuery.XDomainRequest.js (https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest) very helpful

Comment: [Click Here](http://192.168.10.113:8080/solr/select/?q=asp.net%20session%20management&indent=on&hl=true&hl.fl=id,name&wt=json&fl=*,score)
This is my data I want to fetch.
I tried all possible way but did't succeed .
please help to retrieve data from this URL.

Comment: Your server is probably on a private network. I cannnot open the link you sent. Send me an email with a sample of how your data looks. Also please try this code, ` jQuery.ajax({
  url: yourUrl,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
   alert('Success');
  },
  error: function (data) {
   alert('Fail');
  }
    }); ` If you are using chrome, please check the network tab of your inspector(debugging tool) & make sure if you are getting a response.

Comment: Praneeta Can you please share your email id so that i can send the data.

Comment: Thanks Praneeta for your support .
Solved that problem .
your suggestion helped me a lot.
Thanks