# Set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' for multiple domains in Rails 4 application.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cors

In my Rails app, I set CORS to allow `http://someurl.com`. What is the syntax for allowing multiple domains?

My current config in `application.rb`

```
    config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
        'X-Frame-Options' => 'ALLOWALL',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => 'http://someurl.com', # How can I add "anotherurl.com" to this list?
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST GET'
    }
```

The syntax is not mentioned in the guides: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

Comment: Related. This answer doesn't use Rails, but the technique is the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323350/iis-access-control-allow-origin-with-multiple-domains/17329532#17329532

Comment: Hmm that's interesting - I would've figured we'd easily support multiple origins. What is the logic for only allowing one? (Usually there is a good reason for this stuff)

Comment: Also, do you know the technique for this in Rails 4?

Comment: you probably have to add it inside the application controller, and depenend on what origin is sent by the client just add it dynamically to the Access-Ctrl-Allow-Origin. 
Yihang did that: http://www.yihangho.com/rails-cross-origin-resource-sharing/

Comment: ActionDispatch just merges together your headers as a hash, it does no intelligent processing: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/response.rb#L128

This gem https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors  works with Rails as a Rack middleware and will dynamically rewrite your headers allowing for multiple origins.

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41589352/ruby-on-rails-rack-cors-multiple-origins-with-diffrenet-resources