# How to access the WCF client origin in Application_BeginRequest

Tags: c#, wcf

I need to specify the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" as a non-wildcard since my client sends access information through its cookie and sets "withCredentials: true" (and probably good practice to not leave as a wildcard).  I have scoured and found that one way to do this is to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to the client's origin (providing a check that this is an expected origin).

I see how it can be done using PHP...:
[Access-Control-Allow-Origin Multiple Origin Domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains/28552592#28552592)

I also see the following:
[Access-control-allow-origin with multiple domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323350/iis-access-control-allow-origin-with-multiple-domains)

However, my values for WebOperationContext.Current and OperationContext.Current are always null!  I have toyed with service attributes settings with no success.

Any help on why the operation context is null is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

WebOperationContext.Current is null in Application_BeginRequest() I believe since in a thread.  When you access in a service call method, it is accessible.