# How to resolve cross domain error in REST Api while posting on specific group in yammer

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint-2013, yammer

I tried following code post in a specific group in yammer.

```
function post() {
yam.getLoginStatus(
    function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            console.log("logged in");
            console.dir(response); //print user information to the console
            yam.platform.request({ 
                        url: "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json"
                        , method: "POST"
                        , data: { "body" : "Welcome to the Yammer API World.", "group_id":"xxxxxxx"}
                        , CORS: true
                        , dataType: "json"
                        , headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }
                        , xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }
                        , success: function (msg) { alert("Post was Successful!: " + msg); }
                        , error: function (msg) { alert("Post was Unsuccessful..." + msg); }
                    });
        }
        else {
            yam.platform.login(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                   console.dir(response);
                    yam.platform.request({ 
                        url: "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json"
                        , method: "POST"
                        , data: { "body" : "Welcome to the Yammer API World.", "group_id":"xxxxxxx"}
                        , CORS: true
                        , dataType: "json"
                        , headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }
                        , xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }
                        , success: function (msg) { alert("Post was Successful!: " + msg); }
                        , error: function (msg) { alert("Post was Unsuccessful..." + msg); }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

}

in HTML file I have added this code

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-app-id="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" src="https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_js_sdk.js"></script>
```

Code above throws error as 
[image]

Is there any thing I am missing in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made changes in url. Before changes my url was

```
 url: "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json"
```

Now my url is

`url: "https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json"`

It is working fine

Only three characters took my 2 days....

Comment: Upvoted thank
is it possible to get number of comments using this method?

Answer (score 1):

It is nothing to do with JS . you have to add cross origin in your server header.
you have to do something like this in server header

```
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *")
```

Comment: How can I add server header in it

Comment: Can you please explain me it in brief. I am not getting where to put header("Access...")

Comment: The code given in this answer is PHP. The question is tagged sharepoint-2013, so I don't see how PHP is relevant.

Comment: @sandeep.gosavi — Assuming it is generated by PHP, you have to put it in the server side code responsible for generating `https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json`

Comment: I put example of Php. Whichever server you have in that  you can. I used cors lib for flask server

Comment: messages.json is created by yammer itself.

Comment: I found a simmiler question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323350/iis-access-control-allow-origin-with-multiple-domains may be it helps

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, there's a full sample code on how to post messages to a group in yammer here - http://blogs.technet.com/b/israelo/archive/2014/10/21/yammer-js-sdk-for-dummies.aspx