# Response to Preflight responded with 405 Error code : Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, http

I am using an API call in cross domain where In chrome I am getting this response . I have all the headers included in my REST API in other domain .

```
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff"/>
        <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1;"/>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET"/>
```

And this is my API Call from angular .

```
$scope.XYZ=customURLWithoutArray.save({
         controller:"XYZController",
            actionName:"ABCACTIONNAME",
             UserId: "VC"
         },
            function($success){

       return $success;
              },function($error){
      return $error;
    });
```

It is able to hit the controller but data is null.

Comment: Specify the API that you're using and also if you have permission to access the method. So far it returns 405 error so it means you are not allowed to access it.

Comment: This is hosted API and I have permission to access it . I have opened API in debug mode for me and then also tried to hit the same

Comment: And there is no reason for down voting a post .

Comment: Is the API hosted by a third party? Or do you host it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

As you might already know, a preflight request sends a `HTTP OPTIONS` request.

In your configuration (I assume its some IIS server?) you have this:

```
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET"/>
```

Which means you're not allowing `OPTIONS`.

So try modifying it to this:

```
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS/>
```

More information on configuring IIS for CORS:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31084417/6139050