# Can't rewrite Access_Control_Allow_Origin

Tags: .net, url-rewriting, cors

I have one site that works like a cdn for my other sites.

I have added following to Web.config

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE" />
    <add name="Arr-Disable-Session-Affinity" value="True" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>

<rewrite>
  <outboundRules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="AddCrossDomainHeader">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Access_Control_Allow_Origin" pattern=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
        <add input="{HTTP_ORIGIN}" pattern="(http(s)?://((.+\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.ap\.dk|(.+\.)?localhost\:[0-9]*))" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" value="{C:0}" />
    </rule>
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

I was inspired by answer #2 in here [Access-control-allow-origin with multiple domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323350/access-control-allow-origin-with-multiple-domains)

But the rewrite of Access_Control_Allow_Origin does only work on localhost. On live site, it is not rewritten and then I get an error like this:

> Failed to load https://aptestlogin.ap.dk//Widgets/Footer.html: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://aptestproject.ap.dk' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'https://aptestcompany.ap.dk' is therefore not allowed access

In order to load this 'Footer.html' I'll have to clear cache in my brower, and repeat this if I open a another site that calls for this.

Comment: Is IIS works on live directly or via proxy lake a nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Try check regex pattern. Maybe forward slashes is unescaped // or something else.

```
https?:\/\/((.+\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.ap\.dk|(.+\.)?localhost(\:[0-9]*)?)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html

Above will provide a solution for your matter.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors

Open the file App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {

            config.EnableCors(); //add this


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Access_Control_Allow_Origin" pattern=".*" />
```

to

```
<match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Access_Control_Allow_Origin" pattern="*" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in  Visual Studio install the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors from the package manager or Nuget package manager if you have.

Open the file App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs. Add the following code to the WebApiConfig.Register method.

```
using System.Web.Http;
namespace WebService
{
  public static class WebApiConfig
 {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // New code
        config.EnableCors();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
  }
}
```

This enable the cors to the whole application if you want to know more about this CROSS ORIGIN RESOURCE SHARING(CORS) refer over here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api or search in Youtube you'll get a lot of videos for it.