# What are alternatives of Request.UrlReferrer to whitelist redirection from certain domains. CORS on website request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a domain and one page is being accessed by different website. I have tried whitelisting with referrer but am seeing activity from headless browsers.

some website ever i insisted them to add referrer as meta tag but am seeing activity on my page outside my whitelisted domains.

i need much secure way i tried even checking the history page visited but was not successful

How can i stop CROS and allow from certain domains only.

Comment: I cannot do it on server level i need to do this whitelisting on page level as this page got some secure data.
Authorization with token cannot be used

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access-control-allow-origin with multiple domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323350/access-control-allow-origin-with-multiple-domains)