# Angular 6 : 400 bad request when calling API url for getting Auth token

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api, bearer-token, bad-request

In my Angular 6 application I am getting a Http 400 Bad Request error ,while calling the API url for login token .

The API is working fine if I call the same url from POSTMAN.

But giving an error when called from the Angular application.

Service.ts (Angular)

```
Get_User_Token(Email, Password) {
    var data = "username=" + Email + "&password=" + Password + "&grant_type=password";
    var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-urlencoded', 'No-Auth': 'True' });
    return this.http.post(this.BASE_URL + '/token', data, { headers: reqHeader });
  }
```

web.config

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

startup.cs

```
   public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions option = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                AllowInsecureHttp = true
            };
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(option);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
        }
```

Can anyone help me to fix this .

Comment: could you please show us the webapi controller and start up

Comment: please see the updated post @MasoudBimar

Answer (score 0):

first see this post : [Access-control-allow-origin with multiple domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323350/access-control-allow-origin-with-multiple-domains)

then if you need see this page : [Enable cross-origin requests in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

quick guide for Enable cross-origin requests in ASP.NET Web API 2 in three steps:

do the following:
1. first install

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

2.Open the file App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs. Add the following code to the WebApiConfig.Register method:

```
using System.Web.Http;
namespace WebService
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // New code
            config.EnableCors();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

3. Next, add the `[EnableCors]` attribute to the `TestController` class:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace WebService.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "http://mywebclient.azurewebsites.net", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        // Controller methods not shown...
    }
}
```