# Cors access-control-allow-origin header not present

Tags: jquery, cors, owin, katana

I have an owin/katana project. So no IIS.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.Run(context =>
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" }); 
        // etc.
    }
```

and client side this jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: labelPrintLoc,
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
        if (msg === "Done")
            alert("Printed!");
        else {
            alert("Error, check the log on the server!");
        }
    },
    error: function(a, b, c) {
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
        console.log(c);
    }
});
```

[image]

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xxxx:9000
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin http://yyy is therfore not allowed access.

I have seen this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/6516634/169714 but there is no `AppendHeader` method. I thought that the `*` gave everyone access?

**edit** will try option 3 from this url: https://researchaholic.com/2015/04/28/how-to-fix-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-in-asp-net-webapi/

**edit2** adding the nuget and this line
`app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);` and remove the line with headers.add gives me a 500 error, because the origin was already set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a webserver Problem.

Add this to your configuration file. It corresponds to apaches `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`.

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="cors:Origins" value="*" />
  <add key="cors:Headers" value="*" />
  <add key="cors:Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE" />
</appSettings>
```

This will enable cross origin requests for a Katana/Owin setup.

[This article](http://tostring.it/2014/03/04/how-to-use-CORS-with-ASPNET-WebAPI-2/) could be useful too.

Comment: It's selfhosted. Owin/katana

Comment: isn't the system.webserver only for iis? will try 2nd part. Nuget owin.cors gives me problems with duplicate origin header.

Comment: Yes I think you're right for the first, <appSettings> should work for a Katana / Owin setup though

Comment: Seems that the appsettings, the nuget package and the `app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);` fixed it.

Comment: Cool! is it ok if I add this to my answer to make it more complete? If not, feel free to update it yourself.